# How to remove firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Please tell me, how can I delete the entire database from firebase immediately, documentation or other information could not be found, can anyone come across this before?

it,s easy

```
db = Database.database().reference() 
let usersReference = db 
usersReference!.removeValue()
```

Comment: If you found the answer by yourself you should post it as an answer and accept it to keep the place tidy. And fix your syntax error. That won't even compile.

Comment: @Desdenova TY, fix answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db = Database.database().reference() 
let usersReference = db 
usersReference!.removeValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty `JSON` file and import it to firebase database.

Comment: no, it's easy. 
db = Database.database().reference()
let = usersReference = db
usersReference!.removeValue()